# What can I use to send push notification from spring boot to flutter

Tags: flutter, spring-boot, push-notification

I have an flutter app and I need to receive some push notifications from the spring boot server. I will use scheduler and cron to manage when it is going to be delivered. But I don´t know how to send it. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

On flutter side you can use `firebase_messaging` you can follow this [guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview)

On java side you can use `com.google.firebase.messaging` and then follow this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#java)

Comment: Do you know any other way that doesn´t need firebase or azure...?

Comment: @LuisRotoly why do you need another way? firebase_messaging is free